# Can't create new sites and pages in Teamsite

Tags: content-management-system, teamsite, interwoven

I've just installed Teamsite on Linux CentOS 6.5. I've used Silent Installer and mostly default properties (install.properties), I logged in as a root user and everything seems to be good but the problem occurs when I'm trying to create New site or New page. I click as a usual File -> ... and there is only New File, New Branch etc. but there is no New Page or New Site button. Do you know what could went wrong during the installation or what can I do to "restore" this buttons and create sites/pages? Thx.

[image: Teamsite File -> ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are under a Workarea. Create a workarea under a branch and give it a try.

If you are already under a Workarea, then this would the issue with your license. Have you generated right licence from the official license website from HP Autonomy.

The Features are tied to License what you have. Just to cross verify if you do not see SiteMap TAB next to Content and Workflow ( just above file menu ) that indicated you are missing a full licence.

Please generate new licence and try deleting old and start Teamsite server issuing iwreset -a command.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thx for your response. You are right, it was license problem. But the weird thing is that I've installed TS on virtual machine and everything was fine without license (2days trial) ok. I did the same things on new machine and Site Publisher was not working, still don't know why. When I've put my license file of course it has started working.